# AddFolderListener works in some devices but in another doesn´t work

Tags: java, blackberry, directory, listener

I´m developing an app where it listens the messages from an email account and it does an specific action. For that, I use this:

```
public class EmailListener implements FolderListener {

public void registerEmailListener(boolean register) {
ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
ServiceRecord[] srs = sb.findRecordsByCid("CMIME");
if (srs != null) {
ServiceRecord sr;
ServiceConfiguration sc;
/* unregister all email listener  to avoid duplicate listeners */
desregisterAllEmailListeners(srs);
for (int i = srs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
sr = srs[i];
try {
sc = new ServiceConfiguration(sr);
registerEmail(sc, register);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
}

private void registerEmail(ServiceConfiguration sc, boolean register) {
Session s = Session.getInstance(sc);
if (s != null) {
Folder[] folders = s.getStore().list();
for (int foldercnt = folders.length - 1; foldercnt >= 0; --foldercnt) {
Folder f = folders[foldercnt];
// If the folder doesn't have the service book for this email, we do not want to register it
if (f.getFullName().indexOf(sc.getEmailAddress()) >= 0) {
recurse(f, register);
}
}
} 
}
private void recurse(Folder f, boolean add) {
if (f.getType() == Folder.INBOX) {

f.removeFolderListener(this);
if (add) {
f.addFolderListener(this);
}
}
Folder[] farray = f.list();
for (int fcnt = farray.length - 1; fcnt >= 0; --fcnt) {
recurse(farray[fcnt], add);
}
}

public void desregisterAllEmailListeners(ServiceRecord[] srs) {
ServiceRecord sr;
ServiceConfiguration sc;
for (int i = srs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
sr = srs[i];
try {
sc = new ServiceConfiguration(sr);
registerEmail(sc, false);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

public void messagesAdded(final FolderEvent e) {

....

}

....

}
```

When an email has come, it executes messageAdded and does the specific action.  The problem is that in some devices it works, and in another doesn´t work. It registers the email listener correctly in every case, but in some cases don´t execute messageAdded. 
What´s the problem?

It works in: 9300 OS 6.0 and OS 5.0 and 9220 OS 7.1
It doesn´t work in 9320 OS 7.1, 9380 OS 7.1 and 9800 OS 6.0

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!!, it executes messageAdded....debugging. I don´t know why doesn´t show the logs in some devices....

The moral is:
Don´t trust just in logEvent, use this and Debug tool, both!!